# could not read password error while trying to git pull from jenkins using execute shell script on remote hosts

Tags: shell, jenkins, version-control, bitbucket, access-token

I have my code on bitbucket and for the continuous integration part am using jenkins, when i try to execute shell script using git pull command its giving me error
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://solace-rads@bitbucket.org': No such device or address

I tried using access token and pasting the same in git url in jenkins job, but its giving me cannot read password error, tried using https and ssh link using bitbucket username with app password then too didn't work
can you please help me solve this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: basically using jenkins to run scripts in ec2 machines, for authentication instead of using username and password created access token and attached the same in jenkins job, when i try to build its showing "could not read password for https.. no such device"

Comment: I take it you added the username and access token as credentials in Jenkins credential manager? Also, if you are using SSH, verify that they keys are added correctly by logging into the ec2 instance and manually pulling the repo. This problem could also arise if the username of access token has an `@` symbol in it.